# Entity Framework: TPC MapInheritedProperties model super class properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-fluent-api

**Summary**: in Entity Framework I use TPC to create two classes derived from the same base class. In fluent API I map inherited properties, but how to model the properties of the base class?

**More extensive description**
In Entity Framework I have a class Child, and two kinds of Children: a Boy and a Girl. Both Boy and Girl derive from Child:

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
public class Boy : Child
{
    public string SomeBoyishProperty {get; set;}
}
public class Girl : Child
{
    public string SomeGirlyProperty {get; set;}
}
```

I want a table with boys and a table with girls, each table also having the Child properties.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Boy> Boys {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Girl> Girls {get; set;
}
```

[From several sources, for example this one](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) I learned that this is called TPC: table per concrete class and that I should MapInheritedProperties in OnModelCreating

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // model the properties of the base class, for instance set max length
    modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
        .Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(12);

    // Model Daughter:
    modelBuilder.Entity<Daughter>()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("Daughters");
    })
    .Property(p => p.SomeGirlyProperty).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(13);

    // model Boy
    modelBuilder.Entity<Son>()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("Sons");
    })
    .Property(p => p.SomeBoyishProperty).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(14);
}
```

During SaveChanges I get an InvlidOperationException indicating that the primary key is not unique. Removing the part that builds Child solves this problem.

How to build the Child properties without having to do this in the Girl and again in the Boy properties?

Comment: is your `Child` class abstract in your real model?

Comment: Child abstract: I was not planning to create Child objects, only Boys and Girls. Nor do I want to create a Child table. So if I would help to make Child abstract, then I'd do this. I could of course make a Boy a composition of a Child, that would solve the problem, But it seems a bit strange for me that a Boy HAS a Child instead of IS a Child

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

If you want your code to work, remove any reference to `Child` entity in your model configuration. As soon as EF knows about `Child` as Entity it will enforce the following rule: There cannot be 2 entities of type `Child` or 2 entities that inherit from `Child` with the same PK in memory. You can see the error tells you that the entities where successfully persisted; but when EF pulls the new IDs it finds out both have the same ID.

**LONG ANSWER**

Remove

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
    .Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(12);
```

Instead this is how your `OnModelCreating` method should look like.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // Model Daughter:
    var girlEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<Girl>();
    girlEntity.Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("Daughters");
    });
    girlEntity.Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    girlEntity.Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(12);
    girlEntity.Property(p => p.SomeGirlyProperty).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(13);

    // model Boy
    var boyEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<Boy>();
    boyEntity.Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("Sons");
    });
    boyEntity.Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    boyEntity.Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(12);
    boyEntity.Property(p => p.SomeBoyishProperty).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(14);
}
```

If you don't want the configuration repetition in the configuration I would use the `DataAnnotations` attributes on the base class to enforce the name to be required.

You will also need to enforce that the `Id` property to be auto-generated in database. This doesn't happen by convention when using the `Map` method in the fluent API. You can see I added the fluent calls to make that happen in both the `Girl` and `Boy` mapping.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

> I reworked Arturo's solution proposal. This solution was too long to
>   describe as a comment. So **Arturo: thanks for giving me the ideas**.
>   Chapeau!

Arturo suggested to use Data Annotations. The reason that I don't want to use that method is, that the modelling of the class doesn't necessary correspond with a certain database representation. I bit hypothetical, but if I want a smaller maximum length for a boy's Name than for a Girl's name, then a data annotation wouldn't help.

Besides, there are some things that has to be done using fluent API. For instance, you can't say that a `System.DateTime` has a `DateTime2` format in the database using DataAnnotations.

If you didn't guess it already: my problem description was highly simplified. All three classes have a lot of properties that need a lot of fluent API configurations

Arturo's remarks helped me to the following solution:

```
internal class ChildConfig<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : Child
{
    public ChildConfig(...)
    {
        // configure all Child properties
        this.Property(p => p.Name)....
    }
}
internal class BoyConfig : ChildConfig<Boy>
{
    public BoyConfig(...) : base (...)
    {
        // the base class will configure the Child properties
        // configure the Boy properties here
        this.Property(p => p.SomeBoyishProperty)...
    }
}
```

And in MyDbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BoyConfig(...));
    modelBuilder.Configuration.Add(new GirlConfig(...));
}
```

Comment: Excellent use of configuration classes.